# Bootstrap has-success for html 5 forms

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use Bootstrap's `has-success` and `has-error` along with `has-feedback` on HTML5 form inputs as well. But if I do the same thing with number-inputs as what I do with text-inputs, I don't see anything from Bootstrap.

Is it possible at all or is there no support for HTML5 form inputs?

Edit after comment:

`<div class="form-group" class="has-success"> 
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" id="seats_sold"     name="seats_sold" ng-model="group.seats.sold"/> 
</div>`

This is for testing purposes only of course - just to keep it simple. In reality there will be ng-class etc.

Best regards

Comment: can you share your html for the number input that you are using?

Comment: just did so, see my post please